Extract a property from images in an image collection when mapping through it in Google Earth Engine
I have an image collection of 24 images that I want to download. Each image is from a year between 2000 and 2024. I want to export each image using Export.image.toDrive() and the file name of each image should be the year. However, GEE refuses to allow me to get the name of the year.
Here is the code I have:


// create the image collection
var annualCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(annualList);
// create function that downloads each image and returns something 
var download = function(img){
  var stringYear = img.getString('year')
  Export.image.toDrive({image:img, description:stringYear, folder:'snowfree_rasters', fileNamePrefix:stringYear, region:colorado}) 
  return img.date()}
// map function to image collection
var dates = annualCol.map(download)



Outside of the function, img.getString('year') does exactly what you would expect: return the year as a string. Inside the function, it returns a ee.ComputedObject(). Is there anyway to do what I want? I have tried this several other ways to, all with the same results.

The issue is related to client-side and server-side data and operations. Read up on this in the docs for more details.

You cannot export from within a server-side map() callback.
description and fileNamePrefix in toDrive() must be client-side strings.

You can use evaluate() to turn server-side data into client-side.
The below creates a server-side list of system:index, year tuples, which is turned to a client-side array. Based on this, images can be extracted from the collection and exported, using the client-side year.
annualCol
  .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(2), ['system:index', 'year'])
  .get('list')
  .evaluate(function(tuples) {
    tuples.forEach(function(tuple) {
      var index = tuple[0]
      var stringYear = tuple[1]
      var img = annualCol
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', index))
        .first()
      Export.image.toDrive({
        image: img,
        description: stringYear,
        folder: 'snowfree_rasters',
        fileNamePrefix: stringYear,
        region: colorado,
        scale: 100
      })
    })
  })

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c4050716eb567ecb0bc7f33161283cb1
